# Using Task Scheduler to run Script as another User but script is not running

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

This is my first go at task scheduler but I feel like I am pretty close. I get it to pop up and run the task but the script that i specify is not running. When i run the script by itself, it runs just fine.

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$Time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $time -Once
$User = 'DOMAIN\Username' 
$PS = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -file c:\Temp\map_homedrive.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "DiyEusFix" -Trigger $Time -User $User -Action $PS 
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "DiyEusFix"

sleep 10

Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "DiyEusFix"  -Confirm:$false
```

This runs without any issue. The .ps1 file it is trying to run is:

```
$homedir = "\\home\directory\path"
New-PSDrive –Name “F” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "$($homedir)" –Persist
```

I know that keeping track of user context is important with mapped drives, but from my understanding, specifying -User in Register-ScheduledTask should run as the correct user that i want. This is where i think my understanding is disconnecting. I'm thinking it is possible it isn't switching users, but from a syntax point of view it looks right. Any insight would be greatly helpful.

Comment: What is the error code on task scheduler? Are you sure the user has the permissions to run as a job?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The drive just doesnt end up mapping.

Comment: Does the user account have a password associated with it? You don't provide one.

Comment: Yes the user account would have a password associated with it. I want it to be the logged in account.

Comment: Ohhh man, I have a script to do just this! If you can somehow remind me on Monday (when I'm back to work), I will post it here. You also need to make it global

Comment: Perfect. I will reach out. That means i can finally go home for the day haha

Comment: @AbrahamZinala what do i need to make global?

Comment: Need to make the scope global. I will share the script come Monday, just whipped one up yesterday too that runs a task schedule against whoever is logged in on the machine remotely.  Nothing too fancy was just bored and wrote a quick one up.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Just following up with you.

Comment: Heyyy! Sorry man, I can try posting it here after work but, over the weekend my job blocked Stack overflow. Idk why cause other websites work. I did post it here tho: [Run Task Schedule Under Users Context](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4925-run-task-schedule-under-users-context)

Comment: Give that a shot and see if that works for you. I recommend making it a script like we have and using the `-FilePath` parameter. Much easier in my opinion (:

Comment: You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Do let me know if it works out for you, tried adding a small description but, I can give input on what I did when I ran into some issues.

Comment: Okay sounds good. i have to do a bunch of inventory tracking before lunch then i can test it out.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i owe you a beer

Comment: @AbrahamZinala after some messing around with your script i actually was able to get my original to work. However, i will be using that function you created almost daily now lol

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked out for ya(: